# pr2 object manipulation demo code cannot compile

Tags: ros, object-manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the tutorial code from [Write a simple pick and place application](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application)

when I used rosmake to build the node, it brought following errors. It looks like being compiled with wrong header files -> many unknown members of class

```
/home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:171:2: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:171:2: error: stray ‘\267’ in program
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:92:26: error: ‘tabletop_collision_map_processing::TabletopCollisionMapProcessing::Request’ has no member named ‘reset_static_map’    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  ERROR
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:97:26: error: ‘tabletop_collision_map_processing::TabletopCollisionMapProcessing::Request’ has no member named ‘take_static_collision_map’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:126:14: error: ‘object_manipulation_msgs::PickupGoal’ has no member named ‘desired_approach_distance’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:127:14: error: ‘object_manipulation_msgs::PickupGoal’ has no member named ‘min_approach_distance’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:159:55: error: ‘struct object_manipulation_msgs::GraspableObject_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘type’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:159:63: error: ‘DATABASE_MODEL’ is not a member of ‘object_manipulation_msgs::GraspableObject’
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:162:70: error: ‘struct object_manipulation_msgs::GraspableObject_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘model_pose’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  /home/leshawn/stacks_additional/pr2_SHAWNLE/pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:182:13: error: ‘object_manipulation_msgs::PlaceGoal’ has no member named ‘place_pose’ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

I've checked [API doc](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tabletop_collision_map_processing/html/TabletopCollisionMapProcessing_8h_source.html) (I used fuerte but the class members are still similar) to see if there is any change in Class definition so those class members are not available anymore. But the fact is those classes are still the same.

Now I'm confused, dunno what's wrong with it. How can it bring up those errors??

Thank you for any support!!

Edit 01:
I've compiled the code again in Eclipse with GCC C++ with all the necessary inclusion and configuration. And... still the same unknown class members. So, perhaps the class definition has been through updates/changes compared to the ones used in tutorial code and I'll have to adapt the old version to the new code.
If my diagnosis is correct, any hint to speed up this work?? I'm slow at reading such a big ROS header files :((

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48035/pr2-object-manipulation-demo-code-cannot-compile/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-13**:
I'm using fuerte ROS. Therefore, I tried to get the tutorial code for fuerte version and succeeded by printing the according tutorial page of fuerte (still can see the code). Anyway, I can compile it without error now by using the electric tutorial code. Thank you! put your answer sothat I can thk u

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-13**:
I'm using fuerte ROS. Therefore, I tried to get the tutorial code for fuerte version and succeeded by printing the according tutorial page of fuerte (still can see the code). Anyway, I can compile it without error now by using the electric tutorial code. Thank you! put your answer sothat I can thk u

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-13**:
I didn't notice that it is  electric ROS support until you and Lorenz told me. Sadly, it took me hours of debugging and referencing :|

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-14**:
Cool! Can you make your fuerte modifications available somewhere and post it as an answer to this question? Also, all I did was ask a clarifying question, you answered this one, yourself.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-24**:
sure I'll do! but currently not finished yet. I'm still accumulating experience working with ROS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial is for ROS electric. Are you using ROS electric or are you using some other distribution?

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0